# How to include subfolder in packages directory for git?

Tags: c#, .net, git, cvs, gitignore

I've tried searching for this answer on SO but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. I want to include the xUnit.runner package in my solution for building purposes but I can't seem to figure out how to configure the .gitignore file. I've tried this so far:

```
# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# Include the xUnit Test Runner for VSO test runs
!**/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.1/**
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when   needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config
```

I've even tried different iterations with no luck:

```
!**/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.1/*
!**/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.1/
!**/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.1
```

None of these work? Am I ordering the statements incorrectly or something?

Comment: I still haven't got git to include the subfolder but I have gotten my original issue solved. I wanted to include the xUnit runner on Visual Studio Online so it can run tests. Simply including the xUnit Runner nuget package and then setting the "Path to Custom Test Adapters" as $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Packages worked just fine since VSO resolves nuget packages at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your packages folder is in Git root folder
Add this in your Git ignore file

> !packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.0.1

Comment: That didn't work either. If it did it the xunit directory should show up when I do _git status_ correct?

Comment: what is your complete directory structure (from root till packages)?Your xunit directory has some files correct??

Comment: Yes, from root its /packages/xunit... and then there is a bin directory and a file within the xUnit directory.

Comment: hmm is it possible for you to post contents of your git ignore files? make sure contents(file types) of xunit directory is not marked as ignored in git ignore file

Comment: I used the VisualStudio.gitignore file found here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore The only thing I changed was adding the ignore file above.